# Where do you enter the Mercenaries Level for the Catacombs in Resident Evil 6?

Tags: ps3, resident-evil-6

I got Resident Evil 6 (pre-order) for Playstation 3 and it came with a code for the Mercenaries Level (Catacombs). I want to enter the code so I can unlock the level, but I can't figure out where/how to do so. Where do you enter these codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to the Playstation store and in the top-right of the main page is a small icon (one of a set of four I think) that is called redeem codes.

You can enter the code in here and it will allow you access to a download.

[Here are some more detailed instructions](http://uk.playstation.com/redeemvouchercode/).

Comment: Perfect, found it, I still want to look for it in the game menus. :) Thanks!

Comment: @Mike, there is a menu option (I forgot what it is called) in the game, but that just takes you to the PS Store anyway - but when I first tried this it was buggy so I ended up quiting and doing it from the XMB